# Changing UITextView frame

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have `ViewController` with `UITextField`(top view) and `UITextView`(bottom view). I want move `UITextView` to the top of the view, when user start editing it.
When user start editing from `UITextView` everything is fine, but when user first want to edit `UITextField` and then `UITextView` (without hidding keyboard) its not working. `UITextField` is hidden, but `UITextView` don't change his frame.
I tried to use `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` but its called only when keyboard pops up.

Code to reproduce problem:
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleTF;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *bodyTV;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    self.titleTF.hidden=YES;
    CGRect newFrame=CGRectMake(20, 20, textView.frame.size.width, 100);
    textView.frame=newFrame;
}
@end
```

Run app and click on UITextView, app will look like:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/32568213.png
For now everything is fine (UITextField is hidden and UITextView is moved and resized).

Start app again. First click on UITextField and then click on UITextView. App look like this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/66433184.png
UITextField is hidden, but UITextView did not change his frame.

Comment: Does this method fire when you begin editing ? did you try NSLog ?

Comment: Yes, its working. It always hide titleTF.

Comment: Do you only have one textView in this view controller?

Comment: Only one UITextField and one UITextView. I changed line: `textView.frame=newFrame;` to `self.bodyTV.frame=newFrame;` but its work the same.

Comment: Is this the only place where you modify the textView frame? This code seems fine, so the problem is might elsewhere.

Comment: No. I added all code to reproduce problem.

Comment: If you are in hurry, a workaround: implement these two views from code, not from xib. Then this logic worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Move the view up, when the TextView editing begins,
Move it down when editing ends.

Just put these two methods,

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -(textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }];
}

-(void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Not the way I want. It moves root parent, but my UITextView is not full visible, because it is bigger than screen height-keyboard height. I want resize UITextView to fill screen height (left by keyboard).